# Is it necessary to save a downloaded file from an URL before sending it through another REST API?

Tags: java, file, spring-boot

I have a problem regarding handling files using java. In my program i'll have to download a certain file from a URL (this works fine), but then i need to send the same file via a ***REST API*** to save it into a cloud storage.

**My question** now is whether it's necessary to save the downloaded file locally before sending it via the REST API?

Comment: Why should it be? A client that is able to download some data is in general not interested in how a server stores this data actually, all it is interested is that it receives the data upon requesting it. If the server loads the data from a local file storage, from a local or remote DB or from S3 is thereby just an implementation detail not important to clients

Comment: No not necessary... however, in program development it often helps to have that as a middle step in your dev process just so you can confirm that your code is receiving the file correctly from the remote end.  File type/size/encoding, maybe run a checksum of some type on it, etc.  Then worry about uploading.  And when uploading works fine, then you remove that middle code that writes to a file, and go from one remote to local to the other remote.

Answer (score 0):

Ask from yourself - is it OK to loose the file when something happens to your program and it restarts. When saving it locally (in temporary location) then you can continue processing it after your program is again up and running.